# Basic question about functions: Does $f(x) = g(x+y)$ imply that the LHS must be a constant?

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus

The screenshot below shows one way how to derive the probability density function of a normal RV. Check out the red highlighted part. Is this true in general??

Thank you for your help and patience.

**Claim:**  If $f(x) = g(x+y)$ then the LHS is a constant

**Proof:**

Consider any $x_1, x_2$ and let $y_1, y_2$ be such that $x_1 + y_1 = x_2 + y_2$

$f(x_1) = g(x_1 + y_1) = g(x_2 + y_2) = f(x_2) $

Which implies that $f(x)$ is a constant.

**Silly Example**

Let's say $f(t) = g(t) = t$

Then $x = x + y$ implies $y = 0$

Does that also imply $f(t)$ is a constant?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it’s true, and the proof is quite similar to the one in your paper:

> Suppose $f$ and $g$ are functions that satisfy $\forall x\forall y\quad f(x)=g(x+y)$.
>
> Pick any two $x_1,x_2$. We can find a $y$ such that $x_1+y_1=x_2$ then
>   $f(x_2)=g(x_2)$ (by picking $y=0$), $f(x_1)=g(x_1+y_1)$ (by picking
>   $y=y_1$), and $g(x_1+y_1)=g(x_2)$ by definition. By transitivity,
>   $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$. Since $x_1,x_2$ are arbitrary, $f$ is constant.

Your purported counter example doesn’t satisfy $\forall x,y\quad f(x)=g(x+y)$. We have that $f(1)\neq g(1+1)$

Comment: Ah I see your point about my counter example. Thank you. I will meditate on this (as my mind is slow to integrate new ideas).